# Adding Ajax to comments section not Working

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to add Ajax to my comment section to avoid the page refreshing every time a comment is added.

So I load the comments section to the post-details.html from new comments.html and followed the implementing Ajax to posts but my problem is that it is not making any effect and the page needs to refresh to show the new comment

I have sub-classed Generic DetailView class in views.py and trying to figure out a way to return data in JSON format based on an argument received in the URL. Here's what I have tried doing:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            post=post).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                comment_qs = None

                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=self.request.user, content=content)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("blog/post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=self.request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
        else:
            return context
```

But this gave me TypeError as it should be:

```
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse.
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 59, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 268, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
```

In the console I am receiving this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/blog-4/ 500 (Internal Server Error)  jquery.min.js:2
```

Here is the comment section:

```
        <!-- Submit Comment -->
        <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <form action="{% url 'blog:post-comment' post.slug %}" method="post" class="comment-form" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" name="post_id" value='Submit' class="btn btn-outline-success">
<!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>-->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Submit Comment -->

        <!-- Show Comment -->
        <button class="cmt_btn btn btn-outline-info mb-0">Show / Hide {{comments.count}} Comment{{comments|pluralize}}</button>
            <div class="comment-box">
            {% for comment in comments %}
                <ul class="mt-3 list-unstyled">
                  <li class="media">
                    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ comment.post.author.profile.image.url }}">
                      <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{comment.user| capfirst}}<small class="text-muted">- {{ comment.created}}</small> </h5>
                        <hr class="solid mt-0">
                         {% if comment.user == user %}
                          <div>
                            <a class="float-right mr-3" href="{% url 'blog:delete-comment' comment.id%}">Delete </a>
                          </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ comment.content}}
                      </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        <!-- Show Comment -->
```

Here is the scripts

```
    <script>
        $(document).on('submit', '.comment-form', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log($(this).serialize());
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
              $('.main-comment-section').html(response['form']);
              $('textarea').val('');
            },
            error: function(rs, e) {
              console.log(rs.responseText);
            },
          });
        });
    </script>
```

My question is:

What is the reason for getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_context_data` is only for building data for the context not handling an ajax request. You need to split your function to provide handling for GET data

*Example Structure*

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        [...]
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            context = self.get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs)
            html = render_to_string('blog/comments.html', context, request=self.request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})
        [...]
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        [...]
```